# Tinkers construct nothing happend when adding a layer to smeltery

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I made a smeltery with one layer. It works very well, but when I add another layer of seared bricks, nothing happens. Normally, I should be able to put 9 more ores in the smeltery controller, but I can't. the smeltery is working fine with one layer, but doesn't seem to register the extra layer.

**Screenshots**
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Try replacing the glass blocks with seared brick and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Is it just me, or is the floor one block lower than what it should... Or is that just me being weird and forgetting it can be one lower?

Comment: @Tyler6126 what do you mean by that?

Comment: replacing the glass does not fix it.

Comment: @RustyMembers Look behind the controller. The block that (I beleive) should be there isn't, but one block lower.

Comment: oh the floor should be behind the controller? that explains it all :) thank you

Comment: now i can put more then 9 in, but it wont melt...

Comment: @RustyMembers try putting more fuel in and try waiting a little longer. From what I remember, it melts the bottom faster, because of the time change of when you put items in the slot. It might also  be that you are using a material that takes a bit longer to melt, like Obsidian.

Comment: @Tyler6126 when it starts smelting it will show a little red bar at the bottom of the smeltng progress bar. it didn't.

Comment: @RustyMembers that is odd... I'm not sure if it matters, but does it have two controllers or "lava fuel things" (Can't think of the name at the moment)

Comment: @Tyler6126 it does not have to controllers and/or tanks. i odnt think iy should

Comment: @RustyMembers Try updating TConstruct to the latest update, I can't think of anything else, sorry! =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found this to simply be a BUD (block update) issue and can be fixed by removing and replacing the controller, updating the multiblock and letting you use all of the space you have added.

Comment: Note that breaking the controller empties all liquids in the smeltery

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own just now after researching this. I had a small torch on the inside wall to block spawning mobs but the smelter sees this as the new tallest height and you can't add any more even with additional height, check the inside of it it to make sure it is clear of obstructions. If you need a torch to block spawning you can do it on the floor and it won't block the smelter.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a smeltery to work, a few conditions must be met.

1.)There has to be a seared brick floor inside of the smeltery.

2.)The entire thing must be comprised of seared brick, seared glass, or the functional pieces of the smeltery. (Drain, Smeltery Controller, etc.)

3.)It must remain fueled.

4.)All ores to be melted must be input through the smeltery controller, not manually placed inside the smeltery. You are able to throw items in, but It may not always detect it

As long as these conditions are met, there should be no problem.

*Edit:  Also, do not manually break the blocks that show up inside the smeltery when you place them in through the smeltery controller.  This can break your smeltery and cause glitches.

Answer (score 0):

The controller and tank must be on the same level. Other that that, the entire inside must be comprised or entirely seared blocks/bricks, with nothing inside not even a torch. Chiseled blocks work fine too.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case this hasn't been answered yet, if you build the smelter walls higher, you need to move the controller and lava receptacle up as well, i.e. they have to be on the top layer, that will let you add more ores.

Hope this helps

Comment: Really? I've had one working where the controller and lava are on the bottom (read: I have one working with the controller and lava on the bottom layer)

Comment: Not true: the controller and tank can remain on a lower level.